# How to backup a postgres docker image with pg_dumpall

Tags: debian, cron, postgresql, docker

I try to backup a docker postgres container with this cron entry:

```
/usr/bin/docker exec -it container_postgres_1 bash -c 'pg_dumpall -c -U postgres > /pg/sql_`date +%d-%m-%Y"_"%H_%M_%S`.sql'
```

when I execute this line in a shell it works (a backup is created inside of the container.) but the cronjob doesn't work.

The host is a Debian jessy maschine.

Answer (score 1):

the "-it" parameter is not working with docker exec and in cron we have to escape % signs :)

```
@hourly /usr/bin/docker exec container_postgres_1 bash -c 'pg_dumpall -c -U postgres > /pg/sql_$(date +\%d-\%m-\%Y-\%H_\%M).sql'
```